# more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags

Tags: macos, sed

when I use sed in mac OS, I can't use substitute flags like this:

```
sed 's/xx/yy/3g' my.txt
```

what's the replacement for this command?
I cannot use "3g" together here. This use case is in the reference documentation.

I use BSD sed. It show error:

```
more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags
```

Comment: 3 means replace 3.th occurence, g means depending.. after substitution replace all occurences, alone separated with ; means copy hold space to pattern space. What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/x/\ny/3;h;s/x/y/g;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Place a unique marker after the occurences you want to preserve, copy the line to the hold space (HS), replace all occurences then append these to the copy and remove the chunk between the two unique markers.

This method should be accomodated by most sed's. If the sed your using does not handle `\n`'s then use a unique string e.g. `@@a unique string @@`

Comment: my sed doesn't support '\n' in replacement. so I use it like this: `sed 's/s/\'$'\n''xxx/2;h;s/s/xxx/g;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' my.txt`

Comment: I use `sed 's/s/@@xxx/3;h;s/s/xxx/g;H;g;s/@@.*@@//' my.txt`. It works.