# BSD sed (Mac) How to replace from nth occurrence till the end of the line?

Tags: sed, bsd

In `GNU sed` it will be something like this

`'s/foo/bar/3g' <<< "foofoofoofoofoo"`

`Output: "foofoobarbarbar"`

The same command in `BSD sed` gives me a following error

```
sed: 1: "s/foo/bar/3g": more than one number or 'g' in substitute flags
```

How can I implement this on `BSD sed`?

I searched SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056438/more-than-one-number-or-g-in-substitute-flags) but all the answers are for GNU.
I read the man but am having a difficulty figuring this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is implementing a loop using a label and `t` command:

```
$ sed -e ':l' -e 's/foo/bar/3' -e 'tl' <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'
foofoobarbarbar
```

Just be careful because if your replacement text is matched by your original RE (e.g. `s/f.x/fox/`) then you'll be stuck in an infinite loop and if it generates the original text after replacement then you'll get unexpected results, e.g.:

```
$ sed 's/foo/oo/3g' <<< 'foofoofffoo'
foofooffoo
```

```
$ sed -e ':l' -e 's/foo/oo/3' -e 'tl' <<< 'foofoofffoo'
foofoooo
```

Note above that the first version works because it's doing all replacements in 1 pass of the text so the previous replacement isn't considered part of the string for the current replacement pass.

Answer (score 4):

If it's anything other than a simple s/old/new then just use awk instead of sed. With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    cnt  = 0
    while ( match(tail,old) ) {
        tgt = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        if ( ++cnt >= beg ) {
            tgt = new
        }
        head = head tgt
        tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head tail
}

$ awk -v old='foo' -v new='bar' -v beg=3 -f tst.awk <<< "foofoofoofoofoo"
foofoobarbarbar
```

Sure it's a few lines of code but it's extremely common code for solving many problems so it's good to know it, it's easy to see what it's doing, and it's easy to modify to do anything else.

And if you favor brevity over clarity and efficiency you can reduce it to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    head = ""
    cnt  = 0
    while ( match($0,old) ) {
        head = head (++cnt < beg ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : new)
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print head $0
}
```

or even the dreaded "one-liner":

```
awk -v o='foo' -v n='bar' -v b=3 '{h="";c=0;while(s=match($0,o)){h=h (++c<b?substr($0,s,RLENGTH):n);$0=substr($0,s+RLENGTH)}$0=h$0}1' <<< "foofoofoofoofoo"
foofoobarbarbar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without some difficulty.

As noted in the [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) manual:

> **g**
>
> Apply the replacement to all matches to the *regexp*, not just the first.
>
> **number**
>
> Only replace the *number*th match of the *regexp*.
>
> interaction in `s` command Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the `g` and *number* modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the *number*th, and then match and replace all matches from the *number*th on.)

On Mac OS X, however, this works:

```
▶ sed 's/foo/bar/3' <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'          
foofoobarfoofoo
```

As does this:

```
▶ sed 's/foo/bar/g' <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'  
barbarbarbarbar
```

But the error as noted in the question is emitted if they are used together.

[@oguzismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998613/3787051) has provided a clever and simple solution, and I have added this additional explanation because I thought it would be helpful.<sup>1</sup> An earlier version of his answer showed this, which, confusingly, did nothing when tested:

```
▶ sed ':a; s/foo/bar/3; ta' <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'                                                                                                                      
foofoofoofoofoo
```

The BSD manual, meanwhile, provides no explanation either. However, the POSIX manual states:

> The b, t, and : commands are documented to ignore leading white space, but no mention is made of trailing white space.

Thus, this works:

```
▶ sed -e :a -e s/foo/bar/3 -e ta <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'
foofoobarbarbar
```

This also works:

```
▶ sed '
    :a
    s/foo/bar/3
    ta
  ' <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'
foofoobarbarbar
```

In any case, what the script is doing is replacing the 3rd `foo` with `bar`, in a loop, until the replacement fails, at which point the script ends. Note use of `t` (test) which branches only if the previous `s///` command replaced something.

To understand what the script is doing in each of its loop's iterations, this is helpful:

```
▶ sed -n -e :a -e s/foo/bar/3p -e ta <<< 'foofoofoofoofoo'
foofoobarfoofoo
foofoobarbarfoo
foofoobarbarbar
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The original version of that answer had no explanation, although it is much expanded now. Oguz indicated that his preference was for me to add this info in a separate answer.

Comment: Just be aware of the infinite loop if you do `sed -e :a -e s/f../foo/3 -e ta <<< 'foofoofffoo'` and unexpected results if you do `sed -e :a -e s/foo/oo/3 -e ta <<< 'foofoofffoo'` as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998613/1745001

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton and I should add that aside from the learning exercise I completely agree that no one should actually use this code and should use AWK (or Perl etc) for something like this. :)

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution, as it's good enough to get me where I need to be.

Answer (score 2):

Another in awk * for single line processing:

```
$ echo foofoofoofoofoo | 
  awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{RS="foo"}{ORS=NR<n?RS:"bar"}1'
foofoobarbarbar
```

* Tested successfully on gawk, mawk and Busybox awk. Failed on awk-20121220.

Comment: That requires GNU awk for multi-char RS. If the OP wants a non-GNU sed solution, a GNU awk one won't help.

Comment: I'm shocked it worked on Busybox awk - that's not even a POSIX awk. The OPs apparently working with OSX/BSD though and that won't work there.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, I think, that if you had 2 or more input lines then this would treat them as a single line and so every foo from the 3rd one in the first line would be converted to bar rather than the 1st and 2nd foo on every line remaining as foo. idk what the OPs requirements are for that of course. (FWIW the gawk solution I'd go with is based on `split($0,flds,/foo/,seps)`)

Answer (score 2):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ echo 'foofoofoofoofoo' | perl -pe '$c=0; s/foo/++$c<3 ? $& : "bar"/ge'
foofoobarbarbar
```

- `$c=0` for each line of input, initialize counter
- `e` modifier is used to allow Perl code instead of string in replacement section
- `++$c<3 ? $& : "bar"` based on counter, retain or replace the matched text

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/foo/\'$'\n/2' -e 'ta' -e 's/\'$'\n/bar/g' file
```

Set up a loop for the n'th occurrence (in this example 2) and replace it with a unique character/string (in this example newline). When the loop fails, globally replace the unique character/string with the intended string.

Comment: On Mac/BSD that gave me `sed: 1: "s/\<newline> /bar/g<newline> ": unterminated substitute pattern` (I added `<newline>` where literal newlines appeared in the message). The OP and other answers are using 3, not 2, so I was thrown at first by you using 2 as the starting point but this worked: `sed -e ':a' -e 's/foo/\'$'\n/3' -e 'ta' -e 's/\n/bar/g'`. Apparently you must use a literal newline in the replacement text but a `\n` in the regexp. It does require bash for `$'\n'` but that's what you get by default on Mac anyway and you can always use `\<literal newline>` instead of `\'$'\n` otherwise.

Comment: This is the most robust of the sed suggestions, it'd only go into an infinite loop or produce unexpected results if your replacement character was matched by a metachar in the regexp or was present in your input text (which `\n` won't be unless you're "holding" multiple lines at a time so it's usually the best choice), e.g. if you were trying to to `s/[[:space:]]/bar/3g'` and used `\n` as that placeholder so you'd just have to be careful about which placeholder char/string to use wrt what your regexp would match and what char/string might be present in your input.